# find best (uncorrelated) features

Tags: matlab, correlation

suppose that I have my features matrix (rows = observation, columns = features).
I would like to find the best feature(s) for my classification problem.

what I'm doing is

```
%feature matrix
X=rand(10)

%find the correlation matrix of X
r = corr(X)

%sum the r coefficients over the columns 
%(I know that it's not the best way to do this) :)

for i=1:size(r,2)
    vectorsum(i) = sum(r(:,i));
end

%find the feature that is less correlated with the others
bestfeature = min(vectorsum);
```

I'm not totally sure if it makes sense.... but the feature selected should be the least correlated with the other nine... What do you think?

Comment: This link may be helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27750/feature-selection-and-cross-validation

Comment: thanks! very useful link! if I have a clustering problem and I wouldn't like to use cross validation is the correlation between features a valid indicator to select the features to use?

Comment: Yes it's ok, but usually the criteria uses the correlation between feature and classification results as well. you can use function 'sequentialfs' for feature selection in matlab. Also transforming the features using PCA using 'princomp' will result in good classification results.